# Variation on Travelling salesman problem - pick a good subroute from many nodes based on constraints

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, traveling-salesman

**TLDR version:** Most important issue is, that in a TSP problem, instead of finding the shortest Hamiltonian cycle, what are good ways to find the best path (I suppose the one that visits the most nodes) which is at most X length, with a fixed starting point.

***Full version:***

I'm interested in some ideas for a problem that involves TSP. 
First, an example real-world TSP problem is when you have N geographical locations to visit and you need driving directions for an optimal route (or near-optimal) to visit all, either a roundtrip or A to Z. There is a nice JS implementation for this at http://www.gebweb.net/optimap/ and a JS TSP solver available at http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/.

Now consider that you have N = 100 - 1000+ locations. At that point you cannot calculate the route with any reasonable amount of time/resources, but even if it were possible that is not that useful for most real world scenarios. Let's say you pick a fixed starting point and based on that, from those 1000+ locations you want to generate an optimal **subroute** which fits into a (relatively small) **max constraint** (for example, a route that can be covered in 1 day or 1 week).
How can this be solved in near real time?
My thoughts sofar:

1. Build the duration matrix from
   starting point (this step is
   feasible even at a few thousand
   points) and pick a small subset of
   points which are closest to the
   starting point. Ideally this subset
   should be large enough, that
   visiting it fully is definitely >
   **max constraint**, but small enough to process quickly, at least with
   heuristic algorithms.
2. Find an optimal route considering
   the locations chosen in step 1. But
   instead of a route that visits all
   points from this set, I need the
   best route which satisfies **max
   constraint** thus it should not
   visit all points (it **can** visit
   all but that would be the edge
   case). I'm especially not sure on
   how it would be best to tackle this
   one in an efficient way?

Any links, or ideas appreciated, especially for point 2.

**Disclaimer**: Of course the core of the problem is language-agnostic, I'm using JS/Google Maps as an example of real world application.

Comment: I have some ideas but I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Can you offer a real life example? Are you trying to distribute delivery points among several drivers, and then optimize each driver's route?

Comment: @Marcelo - For now I won't consider several drivers at the same time. Let's just say I have 1 driver, 1 starting point for that driver (depot), N available locations and X hours available (ex. 1 day's schedule). Now I want to calculate a route, which maximises this current drivers' efficiency for that timeframe. (route which fits into X hours and maximises number of locations visited/serviced from the N available locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's my sketch of a solution, in pseudo code. You need to know about [Priority Queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)

```
Define a data structure Route {
  the route taken so far, 
  and can give the score (nodes visited)
  the distance traveled
  and the remaining nodes allowed
  the current location.
}

Define a Priority Queue of Routes which sorts on distance traveled.
Define a SortedSet of Routes which sorts on score called solutions.

Add a Route of Length 0, at the depot to the priority queue.
Loop until the head of the priority queue is greater than MAX
   Route r = take the head of the priority queue.
   for each potential remaining node n in r, 
     (in increasing order of distance from the current location)
      child = a new route of r with n appended
      if child distance < max, append to priority queue, otherwise break
   if no children were appended add r to solutions
```

This effectively does a breadth first search of the solution space, in a reasonably memory efficient manner. Moreover, if it is too slow, then when looping over all children you can speed up the algorithm by only taking N nearest neighbors, where N is configurable. You may miss the optimum solution, but it should be reasonable in most cases.

Comment: I've ended up implementing this and it works ok for now. Although it is much slower, compared to ACO + K2-opt heuristic technique or even the dynamic programming exact algorithm, but those are not quite easy to apply to a sub-route search (at least in my limited experience).